# how can I get the result for the [ Promise { <pending> } ]?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I am trying to save bunch of tags into the db and want to get the id in return but I keep on getting the `[ Promise { <pending> } ]`

```
    const tagsArray = tags.split(',');
    const tagIds = await tagsArray.map(async name => {
        return await Tags.findOneAndUpdate({
            name
        }, {
            $addToSet: { user }
        }, {
            new: true,
            upsert: true
        }).then(result => {
            return result;
        })
    });
```

when I try to `console.log(tagIds)` I only get `[ Promise { <pending> } ]`

I used to write without the `.then()` but still doesn't work though.

How can I get the result?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're `.map`ping each tag to a `Promise` in an array, but you can't `await` arrays (meaningfully), you can only `await` Promises

Comment: @CertainPerformance so I shouldn't be using `Promise` ?

Comment: Didn't say that - check out the linked question

Comment: @CertainPerformance sryz I meant `map` not `Promise`.  I will read the link :D thx thx

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for the link, I think I am posting the question wrong.  I should be asking how to `push` into an array in a promise.  Let me re-edit my question

Comment: You can only await `Promises`, so, change to `const tagIds = await Promise.all(tagsArray.map...`

Comment: @CertainPerformance thx thx a lot, I was using `Promise.all(tagIds).then().....` which didn't work too so was trying it.  But putting `Promise.all()` right in front works like a charm.  Thanks thanks